# Flask raises 404 for blueprint static files when using blueprint static route

Tags: python, flask

I have a blueprint, `home`, with the prefix `/` on my Flask app. The blueprint has a static folder and is configured with the `static_folder` argument. However, linking to the blueprint's static files returns a 404 error, even though the file exists and the url looks right. Why doesn't the blueprint serve the static files?

```
myproject/
    run.py
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        home/
            __init__.py
            templates/
                index.html
            static/
                css/
                    style.css
```

`myapp/init.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

from myproject.home.controllers import home

application.register_blueprint(home, url_prefix='/')
```

`myapp/home/controllers.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

home = Blueprint('home', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

@home.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`myapp/home/templates/index.html`:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('home.static', filename='css/style.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

`myapp/home/static/css/style.css`:

```css
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should move your blueprint to init.py file?

Comment: No error, just a white page. The body tag does not have any css style, I can't see the backgroun.

Comment: and this is more defenation of my project from my last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828711/flask-blueprint-sqlalchemy-cannot-import-name-db-into-moles-file/41839910#41839910

Answer (score 12):

You are getting a conflict with the Flask static folder and your blueprint. Since the blueprint is mounted at `/`, it shares the same static url as the app, but the app's route takes precedence. Change the static url for the blueprint so it doesn't conflict.

```
home = Blueprint(
    'home', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static',
    static_url_path='/home-static'
)
```

Comment: I did, now facing with this error `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'static' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'home.static' instead?`

Comment: I see the problem, change your `url_prefix='/'` to `url_prefix=''` in your `__init__.py`

Comment: I did but still the same error. Does it back to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('home.static', filename='css/style.css')}}">` line?

Comment: Before you said you were not getting an error, now it's getting this? I have your complete project setup (based on another of your questions), and this is working 100% for me.

Comment: Are you sure you are putting in the right code? This error is if you have filename= in the wrong spot, or it's missing.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I'm putting int he right code. none of the solutions worked for me and don't understand why :|

Comment: By changing `static_url_path='/home-static'` from home bluprint to `'/static'` and deleteing `static_folder=None` from `application = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)`, I will get the white page again instead of that error.

Comment: I had to set my `url_prefix` to `url_prefix=''` I had it as `/` for home pages but didn't allow any other pages inside that blueprint to be accessed.

Answer (score 6):

Finally on the base of friend's answers, I found the correct answer myself.
The only changes should be like this:

myapp/init.py:

```
application = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)
```

myapp/home/controllers.py:

```
home = Blueprint('home', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static', static_url_path='static')
```

myapp/home/templates/index.html:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('home.static', filename='style.css')}}">
```

Comment: This was helpful, although for me I set my public blueprint like so: `static_folder='../static', static_url_path='/static'`, with nothing in my main app call. I was then able to successfully able to reference it as `src="{{ url_for('public.static', filename='img/......`