# Cannot import name 'db' (flask, sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, flask, import, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to import database and get an error "cannot import name 'db'". I've seen answers on such problem, but none of them helped in my case.
Tree of my project:

```
chat
  | chat.py
  └─ app
      │   models.py
      │   __init__.py
      │
      ├─── main
      │      events.py
      │      forms.py
      │      routes.py
      │      __init__.py
```

chat.py:

```
from app import create_app, socketio

app = create_app(debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

app\init.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gjr39dkjn344_!67#'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql:///site.db'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    socketio.init_app(app)
    return app
```

app\main\init.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from . import routes, events
```

app\models.py:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    session_id = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    isready = db.Column(db.Boolean, default='False')
    room = db.relationship('Room', backref='spy')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}')"
```

So, when I'm trying `from app import db` in python terminal I get

> ImportError: cannot import name 'db'

Since I'm new to flask (and web at all), I have no idea, what to do. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828711/flask-blueprint-sqlalchemy-cannot-import-name-db-into-moles-file) (kinda closest to my case) and all alike answers but it didn't work.
What can I try?

Answer (score 1):

`db` is just a local variable in the `create_app()` function. You'll need to create that object *outside* of the `create_app()` factory.

You can create the Flask-SQLAlchemy `db` plugin object *without* passing in an `app` argument, and in the factory connect that object to te Flask `app` with the `.init_app()` method, just like you already do for the Flask-SocketIO plugin:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gjr39dkjn344_!67#'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql:///site.db'

    db.init_app(app)
    socketio.init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

Now `db` is available as a global in the module, and so can be imported elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I got another problem.
"No application found. Either work inside a view function or push" when I try to db.create_app(). So I did it using "with app.app_context()" as it recommended in documentation, but now I can't import classes. I get "ImportError: cannot import name 'User'"

Comment: @elephantsdadshusband: those are new, independent issues. You could post those as new questions.

Comment: @elephantsdadshusband: put differently: I can't solve those problems *here*, I don't have enough information nor should this question be altered to add those details. *This* specific problem has been solved, and is useful for future visitors with the same problem (which is what SO is all about).